# no apps can perform this action android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Im new to this area, I have a mission, I have build up an application that register some data that I have insert.
lets call this app "A", now i copy the same app and called it "B".
In app "A" and "B" in the manifest file I write this:

```
<activity
            android:name=".Register"
            android:exported="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.action.ex3.register" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Now in app "C" I want to use what app "A" or "B" doing, in order to to that in the app "C" I write this:

```
public void registerBtnClicked(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(); //implicit activity.
        intent.setAction("com.action.ex3.register");
        startActivityForResult(intent, REGISTER_ID);
    }
```

what I expected that will happen it that when I press in my app "C" on the regiser button a pop out with a "chooser dialog" with option to choose "A" or "B", but instead of that I got  "chooser dialog" with "no apps can perform this action android studio"

what im doing wrong?
here a picture of the problem

[App C "no apps can perform this action android studio"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/43fZJ.png)

**Im using pixel emulator in android studio IDE.**

Answer (score 3):

Your activities are not exported. They cannot be accessed from other apps. Change `android:exported` to be `true` if you want other apps accessing your activities.

Comment: Thank you, changed this attribute and this works as I wished :)